# Java package that converts rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: java, metadata, coordinate-systems

I need to convert rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. Can you recommend a library that I can use, I would rather not have to write this myself.

This is used for making sense of metadata included in astronomy image files.

Comment: Umm ... the calculation should be simple, and it would probably really help your understanding of the problem domain if you looked up the formulae and implemented them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the standard library already has this. If there are imaginary number types, they do precisely this (real = x, imag = y, arg(val) = angle, abs(val) = radius). Using the math library (atan2, sin, cos and sqrt) isn't that difficult either.

Answer (score 1):

isn't this just like 2 functions? surely you could just search for it in any language and convert it yourself.

here is my code to do rectangular -> polar  (the other way is very easy) in c++

```
Vector3 C2P (const Vector3 &v)
{
        float PI=3.14159260f;
        Vector3 polar;
       polar.x = v.Length();

       if (v.z > 0.0f) {
              polar.y = (float) atan ( v.z/sqrt (v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y));
       }
       else if (v.z < 0.0f) {
               polar.y = (float) -atan (sqrt (v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y) / v.z);
        }
        else {

                polar.y = 0.0;
        }


        if (v.x > 0.0f) {
                polar.z = (float) atan (v.y / v.x);
        }
        else if (v.x < 0.0f) {
               polar.z = (float) atan (v.y / v.x) + PI;
        }
        else if (v.y > 0) {
                polar.z = PI * 0.5f;
      }
     else {
              polar.z = -PI * 0.5f;
        }
       //polar.z=(polar.z/M_PI)*180;
       //polar.y=(polar.y/M_PI)*180;
       return polar;
}
```

note the result is x = length, y = angle1 z = angle2, in radians.

EDIT:
by my code, I mean some code that I stole from somewhere and used like once.

Comment: Crappy implementation. You should be using atan2 instead of atan to avoid the if-elses.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a [Map Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) Library. One of the most popular open source libraries are [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) and there is one [Java Implementation](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) of it.

You have to decide what projection you want to use. They have different properties. [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) is common and is the one that Google Maps is using. The disadvantage with Mercator is that you can not use it around the arcitc poles.